# Restrict main site user access in sub site

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site called www.example.com; it has its own users account. Now I have created a sub site called www.yy.example.com. I have installed Multisite user management so that example.com site users can log in yy.example.com site. In yy.example.com I have restricted user registration in frontend; since users are registered by backend admin panel. In front end I have log-in form using frontend membership plugin. Now I want to restrict the access of example.com users in yy.example.com.

How to do this?

Comment: Not so difficult, I think... But, please, provide more details and show the code you are working with. Or said in other way: what did you find in your research? You did research, right?

Comment: At the beginning I used Multisite User Management plugin to give both site users can access both main site and sub site.  Because of this there may some additional information may be inserted in database table.  I need to find out that.  Now I want the main site users should not access subsite.  In subsite I will create users in admin panel. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not really sure of what's your issue, what's the scenario it is happening, what do you expect and what doesn't work... Yes, lots of doubts, your description is really short, please check the page [ask] and its related links. :::: Anyway, [does this help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13452961/1287812)?

Comment: Sankar, [edit] the Question and include these details. I'm not sure how to do this, I don't know the plugin... But whomever stumbles upon the Q should know all of it without reading the Comments.

Comment: Thanks brasofilo.  I have updated my question.